# C File handling in visual studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

The file handling commands in Visual Studio seem to be different than normal. I'm currently learning the very basics of File Handling in C, but the commands don't seem to be working. This is what I've got right now -

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
{
   int num;
   FILE *fptr;
   fptr = fopen("C:\\", "program.txt", "w");

   if (fptr == NULL)
  {
      printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
  }

    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    fprintf(fptr, "%d", num);
    fclose(fptr);

     return 0;
}
```

Here's the build output-

> 'fopen': too many actual parameters
>
> warning C4013: 'exit' undefined; assuming extern returning int
>
> error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
>
> fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

When I use fopen_s instead, like this fopen_s("C:\program.txt", "w"), it says-

> 'function': 'FILE **' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [15]'
>
> 'fopen_s': different types for formal and actual parameter 1
>
> 'fopen_s': too few arguments for call
>
> '=': 'FILE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'errno_t'

I need some serious help.

Comment: `exit` is declared in `stdlib.h`, so `#include <stdlib.h>` to handle that error. For small programs, I would recommend opening the `VS Developers Command Prompt` and learning to compile from the command line. Much faster than using the IDE, and you also learn what the compiler options are -- so you can then tell the IDE what you want it to do. A minimum command line would be `cl /W3 /wd4996 /Ox /FeNameForExe /Tc yoursource.c`. Which would compile `yoursource.c` and create `NameForExe.exe`. No project, no solutions, no pre-compiled headers -- just C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open your file with either

FILE * f;
f= fopen("C:\\program.txt", "w");

or

FILE * f;
int err = fopen_s(&f, "C:\\program.txt", "w");

the latter takes FILE ** as an extra argument, and return error code (0 on success).

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain the err bit? and the part "&f" part, to access the adress of f, shouldn't I declare it first? should I do FILE *f for it then?

Comment: FILE *f; // this declaration is common for both examples. so yes, you have to declare it first; regarding the "inte err= fopen_s(...)", this is an API change. fopen_s returns error status, (0 on success) and it returns FILE object through the first argument (this is why you have to pass a pointer to it)

Answer (score 0):

There is a extra comma `,` in `fopen()` which makes `fopen()` as three arguments, which is wrong & causing the error

> 'fopen': too many actual parameters

This

```
fptr = fopen("C:\\", "program.txt", "w"); /* fopen() expects 2 arguments */
```

replaces with

```
fptr = fopen("C:\\program.txt", "w");
```

You can disable below

> 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe.  Consider using
>   fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

warning by

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)     /* use it before other headers */
```

Or use `fopen_s()`.

Comment: Compiling from the command line `/wd4996` will disable the warning as well.

Comment: That's very informative & handy solution @DavidC.Rankin I didn't try it before.

Comment: Yes, when I would compile using the `/Wall` warning level for VS from the Developers Command Prompt -- I have a standard string of `/wdXXXX` warnings to disable all the unwanted non-code warnings. I finally got tired of how chatty `/Wall` can be and just went with `/W3`, verbose enough, but primarily code-related warnings. (`/wd4996` would still be required there) You can enter as many `/wdXXXX` options as you like where `XXXX` is the warning number you want to suppress. `cl /?` explains it well.